# IUSR vs. Application Pool credentials

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, authentication, permissions

I have a  IIS7/ASP.NET application running with the following configuration:

1. Anonymous authentication (IUSR).
2. Application Pool running as a domain account

If IUSR is denied the "logon locally", then it appears that ASPX pages will still render their HTML, but static content such as images will not be delivered.  I'm wondering what the technical reason is for this?  If IUSR is "broken", why will a request to an ASPX page be passed down the pipeline and executed, but IIS will refuse to serve an image in the same directory?

Comment: @jlew: are you sure the logon locally has anything to do with it? It sounds more like you might be missing the "Static Content" role service from the Web Server role.

Comment: Definitely related to the presence/absence of that privilege.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MattB that it's likely not because of the logon locally setting.

As a side, if you set the anonymous user to use the app pool identity, you only need to maintain 1 user.  That's my preferred setting.  Note that you should map 1 site to 1 app pool, or all sites in the app pool need to trust each other.  If that's not the case then keep it with the defaults.